# How to get an object's name after it's sent to a function, within a tibble?

Tags: r, tibble

I want to get an object after it's sent to a function. This question has been solved many times before on this site with a `deparse(substitute(x))` trick. I am getting unexpected behavior when I use this within a `tibble`.

```r
my_df <- function(x){
  data.frame(varname = deparse(substitute(x)))
}


my_tibble <- function(x){
  tibble::tibble(varname = deparse(substitute(x)))
}
  
my_df(outcome) # works as expected
#>   varname
#> 1 outcome
my_tibble(outcome) # uses argument name instead of object name
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   varname
#>   <chr>  
#> 1 x
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

This is only a partial answer. You could make your code work using `!!` but I have to confess that I can't explain why we have to do it this way:

```r
my_tibble <- function(x) {
  tibble::tibble(varname = !!deparse(substitute(x)))
}

my_tibble(outcome)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   varname
#>   <chr>  
#> 1 outcome
```

Comment: Since SO is stuck with too many pending edits I'm gonna put some additional infos here as a simple comment. `deparse(substitute(x)) ` will just give you `x` because `deparse(substitute...` will just give you the name of the argument to that function ie `x`; since `tibble` is "super-lazy" you will use `!!` (bang-bang) to force evaluation of the argument here `x` which will return `outcome`

Comment: that eager evaluation via `!!` relies heavily on the bang-bang operators very high precedence (basically same as that of unary operators like `+`, etc.)

Comment: @user2554330 there is no `!!` operator in R  in the same way that there is no `tibble` object in R ;-)      
it's a `rlang` construct (have a look at injection operators in its docs or a web search on bang-bang or other injection operators) and `rlang` gets imported by `tibble`

Comment: @GWD:  sorry, you're right.  I've deleted my two comments.  Before doing tidy evaluation of an expression like `!!a + b`, `rlang` manipulates the parse tree to make it look as though `!!` is really an operator.

Answer (score 2):

This is a design flaw in tidy evaluation.  In order to allow ugly constructions like

```
x <- 1
tibble(x = 2, y = x)
```

(which gives values `2, 2` instead of the standard `2, 1` in the result) it doesn't evaluate arguments in the context of the caller, it constructs a new environment  and evaluates them there.  Usually that doesn't give surprising results, but `substitute()` also does
nonstandard evaluation.  If you call

```
 deparse(substitute(x))
```

at top level or in a function that doesn't have an argument `x`, it will just return `"x"`.  What `tibble(varname = deparse(substitute(x)))` does is a more complicated version of this:

```r
f <- function(x) {
   env <- new.env()
   eval(quote(deparse(substitute(x))), envir = env)
}
f(outcome)
#> [1] "x"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

which evaluates `substitute(x)` in the new environment where there's no `x`, so you just get `"x"` back.

@stefan's answer shows how to restore standard evaluation semantics using the `!!` prefix.  Another solution is just to avoid using `substitute()` in a tidy evaluation context, e.g. change your function to

```
my_tibble <- function(x){
  thename <- deparse(substitute(x))
  tibble::tibble(varname = thename)
}
```

This adds an extra line to your function, but saves you from trying to read the help page `?"!!"`, so I think it's worth it.